# Chrome extentsion: Call function in contentscript.js from background.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to call function in contentscript.js from background.js but getting an error "Unchecked runtime.lastError: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist." Any ideas?

**background.js**

```
function change_ua(){
    var ua_list = [
        'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.100 Safari/537.36',
        'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3835.0 Safari/537.36',
        'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3790.0 Safari/537.36',
        'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3818.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/77.0.189.3'
    ];

    var randomise_UA = Math.floor(Math.random() * ua_list.length);
    random_UA = ua_list[randomise_UA];

  content_script_call();
};


function content_script_call() {
  chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {greeting: "hello"}, function(response) {
      console.log(response.status);
    });
  });
};
```

**contentscript.js**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function(request, sender) {
    if (request.greeting == "hello"){
        some_function();
        sendResponse({status: 'function called'});
    }
});

function some_function(){
    alert("function test");
};
```

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "background":{
    "run_at": "document_start",
    "scripts": ["jquery.js", "background.js"],
    "persistent": true
  },

  "content_scripts": [{
      "run_at": "document_start",
      "js": ["jquery.js", "contentscript.js"],
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"]
  }],

  "permissions": [
    "proxy",
    "tabs",
    "browsingData",
    "notifications",
    "http://*/",
    "https://*/",
    "activeTab",
    "storage",
    "webRequest",
    "webRequestBlocking"
  ],

  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

aaaaaaaaaaa

Comment: It means that the tab didn't have the content script running at the time you were sending the message. Show your "content_scripts" section of manifest.json and describe when and how content_script_call() is called. Also don't use `alert` inside the onMessage callback as it may break messaging functionality. Use console.log and/or proper debugging with breakpoints in devtools.

Comment: @wOxxOm manifest added, content_script_call() called after another function

Comment: After which function? Timing is the key here so be specific. Also `"run_at": "document_start"` won't do anything inside `"background"` section. Do you have devtools window active at the time content_script_call() runs?

Comment: @wOxxOm added, this function just gives me string from array and call content_script_call()

Comment: So it's not inside an API event listener? The code you've posted runs content_script_call() when the background script is initialized which happens on the startup of the browser when a random tab is active which may be a chrome:// UI tab or the empty new tab page, and these can't have content scripts. This entire workflow doesn't make sense to me in its present state so what specifically do you want to implement here?

Comment: @wOxxOm i just want to call some_function() in contentscript.js from background.js

Comment: Background script can only call anything from content script if the active tab has some page/URL loaded to. But, as @wOxxOm noted, your code runs once at the browser's startup, so the active tab is most likely an empty tab without content script at this moment. That's why you get that error. The best solution would be to call `content_script_call()` upon some user action, e.g. browser popup click.

Comment: @Tony, what you want to achieve by calling the function is what I wanted to know in order to suggest a working solution. The fact that you want to call the function is already obvious from the question and I'm smart enough to understand that.